# Add SIP header when originating via Asterisk callfile

Tags: sip, asterisk

I need a way to add SIP headers when originating a call using an Asterisk callfile.

Is there any way to add SIP header in the call file?

I know I can accomplish this using Asterisk AGI, but I am not able to find any solution to add a SIP header using a call file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Set: __SIPADDHEADER1=X-foo:bar`

Make sure you increment the number, "N" at the end of `__SIPADDHEADERN` to `1`, `2`, ... `100` etc. You'll have trouble adding multiples otherwise

Here's a (granted, modified) example from a callfile I use to issue test calls to my platform:

```
Channel: SIP/foodevice/8025551212
Callerid: 8025551111 <some dude>
MaxRetries: 0
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 30
Context: testplan_origination
Set: __SIPADDHEADER1=X-testplan:testing1234
```

Note that the `Context:` line would allow you to also do this by entering into a dialplan context, and you can do what you may with the call from there, using @arheops suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

### PJSIP Channels

When using a PJSIP channel, using the function [`PJSIP_HEADER`](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+12+Function_PJSIP_HEADER) is available:

```
Channel: PJSIP/121
Application: Milliwatt
Set: PJSIP_HEADER(add,Alert-Info)=<urn:alert:service:normal>;appearance=4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can dial via Local channel, via dialplan

No any issues add sip header in dialplan.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+local+channels

Comment: This doesn't answer the original questioner's question.